# Why doesn't the variable stay when I am using the setTimeout method?

Tags: javascript, scopes, lexical-scope

```
var obj = {
    id: 1,
    getId: function(){
        console.log(this.id)
    }
}

obj.getId(); // 1

setTimeout(obj.getId, 1000); // undefined
```

So I am trying to understand that calling the method directly is doing well but when I call it using the setTimeout method, the scope somehow disappears. Why is that? Is that a flaw in the language or is there something else going on behind the scenes that I don't understand entirely.

I even tried `var self = this;` in the `getId` method but it still would say `self.id` is undefined. What is going on?

PS: I am using node v6.5.0 to run this code through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the ThisBinding (the value of `this` inside of a function) when passing the function reference that way.

Instead, pass `obj.getId.bind(obj)`.

```
setTimeout(obj.getId.bind(obj), 1000);
```

Think about it like there is a bunch of functions in memory, and if you call one with `obj.getId()`, you're telling it to pass *`obj`* as its ThisBinding.

However, if you pass simply `obj.getId`, you are simply giving it a function reference to some function, and it doesn't know which object it should use as the context (so it will default to the global object). Using `Function.prototype.bind()` can *lock-down* the ThisBinding to your choosing.

Comment: So you mean if I do `var id=2` outside the object, the program should output 2, right?

Comment: @Rohan Yes, if you declare it in the global scope.

Comment: I tried it and it still says undefined. Which is why I got more confused.

Comment: Try with  `this.id = 2` in the global scope

Comment: @Rohan It should work if you are defining the variable in global scope, which will be added to window object. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y79ejLh4/1/